Rear derailer missing and needing correct one, schwinn with numbers on bike in question..it is a newer model .maybe a trailways but not certain of mo
I have been gifted a schwinn that needs a rear derailer with numbers 365505 snxds 21h16996. Can you assist me in getting the correct derailer?

Welcome to the site!    Serial numbers aren't any use - a clear photo of your bike, or the model and approximate age would help.  Also, check the shifter and see how many detents it has, including the first/last position... that tells us the number of "speeds"

Most likely a Tourney on that level.
Count the number of cogs (7 or 8, maaaaybe 9) and source an appropriate derailleur.
